# How to pass a vendor-specific options to a DHCP server using dhclient?

Tags: linux, dhclient, dhcp-option

I need to send vendor-options to DHCP server using dhclient (ISC).
As I understand I need to describe that options in the dhclient.conf.

Do I need make new "space" for options? Or I can do "send"?

Can someone help me with this or give me, please, any good examples/ links to text.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've got kinde os loution:

option dhcp6.vendor-class code 16 = {integer 32, integer 16, string};
option dhcp6.vendor-sub-option-deviceType code 17 = {integer 32, integer 16, integer 16, string};

send dhcp6.vendor-class 4491 12 "OpenCable2.1";
send dhcp6.vendor-sub-option-deviceType 4491 2 4 "ESTB";

Does someone can make it better? I need send a lot of options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came to this solution:
in your config file add
`00:00:11:8b:00:02:00:04:45:53:54:42` - this is hex string

```
send dhcp6.vendor-opts 00:00:11:8b:00:02:00:04:45:53:54:42;
```